# How can i vertically center a background image using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, background, position, center

So i've been trying to create a parallax effect with my background image on my webpage but sadly iOS devices apparently force backgrounds to be "background-attachment: scroll" to save on battery/performance.

After some reseacrh i found this jQuery that will be able to replicate the parallax effect and have my background image follow the users scrolling:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.parallax').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY )) + 'px');

});
```

It works but unfortunately the code does not vertically center my background image. the " 'center ' " portion of the jQuery does center my background image horizontally but i need a way to also center it vertically.

Thanks!